# tramp gcloud compute ssh not working

Tags: spacemacs, org-babel, tramp

I wanted to be able to ssh into my google cloud instances with spacemacs. I found:
 https://github.com/dustinfreeman/dustinfreeman.emacs.d/blob/master/init.el#L50

which is based off of:
https://qiita.com/tanatana/items/218b19808f2428b125fe

I added

```
(require 'tramp)
(add-to-list 'tramp-methods
             '("gcssh"
               (tramp-login-program        "gcloud compute ssh")
               (tramp-login-args           (("%h")))
               (tramp-async-args           (("-q")))
               (tramp-remote-shell         "/bin/sh")
               (tramp-remote-shell-args    ("-c"))
               (tramp-gw-args              (("-o" "GlobalKnownHostsFile=/dev/null")
                                            ("-o" "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null")
                                            ("-o" "StrictHostKeyChecking=no")))
               (tramp-default-port         22)))
```

in my `.spacemacs` file under the `dotspacemacs/user-init` function. However, if I `spc f f` and then type `/gcssh:` I get the following error in the `*debug tramp*` buffer.

```
  backtrace()
  tramp-error(nil user-error "Not a Tramp file name: \"%s\"" "/gcssh:")
  apply(tramp-error nil user-error "Not a Tramp file name: \"%s\"" "/gcssh:")
  tramp-dissect-file-name("/gcssh:")
  helm-ff--create-tramp-name("/gcssh:")
  helm-ff-update-when-only-one-matched()
  run-hooks(helm-after-update-hook)
  helm-log-run-hook(helm-after-update-hook)
  #[0 "\301\206\006\0\303 \304\001\236\204\031\0\211\203\025\0\305\001\306\"\210\307\310!\210\210\300\203N\0\311\312\300\"\210\313 \203I\0\314\313 !r\315\316\317\320\321\005!\322\"\323$\216\324\001@\325\"\210\326\300\301\"\210*\210\202N\0\326\300\301\"\210\327\211\022\207" [nil nil helm--force-updating-p helm-get-current-source candidates-process helm-display-mode-line force helm-log-run-hook helm-after-update-hook helm-log "Update preselect candidate %s" helm-window internal--before-with-selected-window make-byte-code 0 "\301\300!\207" vconcat vector [internal--after-with-selected-window] 2 select-window norecord helm-preselect nil] 7]()
  helm-update()
  helm-check-new-input("/gcssh:")
  helm-check-minibuffer-input()
  #[0 "\010\206\005\0\011?\205 \0\302 r\303\304\305\306\307\005!\310\"\311$\216\312 \210\313 *\262\001\207" [helm-in-persistent-action helm-suspend-update-flag internal--before-save-selected-window make-byte-code 0 "\301\300!\207" vconcat vector [internal--after-save-selected-window] 2 helm-check-minibuffer-input helm-print-error-messages] 7]()
  apply(#[0 "\010\206\005\0\011?\205 \0\302 r\303\304\305\306\307\005!\310\"\311$\216\312 \210\313 *\262\001\207" [helm-in-persistent-action helm-suspend-update-flag internal--before-save-selected-window make-byte-code 0 "\301\300!\207" vconcat vector [internal--after-save-selected-window] 2 helm-check-minibuffer-input helm-print-error-messages] 7] nil)
  timer-event-handler([t 0 0 10000 repeat #[0 "\010\206\005\0\011?\205 \0\302 r\303\304\305\306\307\005!\310\"\311$\216\312 \210\313 *\262\001\207" [helm-in-persistent-action helm-suspend-update-flag internal--before-save-selected-window make-byte-code 0 "\301\300!\207" vconcat vector [internal--after-save-selected-window] 2 helm-check-minibuffer-input helm-print-error-messages] 7] nil idle 0])
```

Additionally, I tried to use org-babel to connect but nothing happens.

Any ideas, would be greatly appreciated. All the online postings made me believe that it was straight forward. So maybe there is something I'm missing as I am new to `emacs`,`spacemacs`, and `tramp`.

Comment: First question for you, maybe an obvious one, but did you re-evaluate your `.spacemacs` file after you added the configuration for `tramp`?  Either with `SPC f e R` or restarting Emacs?

Comment: Second, assuming you did do that, maybe this issue https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/2090 will help?  Sounds like you either change the Tramp syntax to simplified with `M-x tramp-change-syntax` or type your path like `/ssh:gcssh:`.  You'll have to ask another question about `org-babel`, it isn't clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ah, thanks @shoshin for taking the time to look at this. Yeah, I did run through the basic tests. From the link, you sent me, I'm not sure if it's due to my emacs version (I'm on 26.1). I tried downgrading my version to 25.3 with no avail so it can't be said for certain. Regardless, I attempted the `/ssh:gcssh:<user>@<instance>:` and it failed with `ssh: Could not resolve hostname gcssh: nodename nor servname provided or not known^M`. Additionally, `M-x tramp-change-syntax` only yielded one option `default`. Lastly, for the `org-babel` I just assumed, maybe naively one would resolve the other.

Comment: `/ssh:gcssh:<user>@<instance>:` is not a valid Tramp name. You have defined `gcssh` as method, so you must use it like `/gcssh:<user>@<instance>:` I suppose.

Comment: `SPC f f` and then `/gcssh:` results in the `*debug tramp*` error I originally posted.

Comment: I found a workaround I've updated my ~/.ssh/config file with 
`Host <instance_name>
    HostName <instance_external_ip>
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine
    UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
    CheckHostIP=no
    StrictHostKeyChecking=no` 
Not a solution but I can use the native ssh functionality fine. :)

Answer (score 5):

If you just run `gcloud compute config-ssh` in the terminal regular ssh tramp will find the instances that are accessible.